# react.js - Render on requestAnimationFrame

Tags: javascript, render, requestanimationframe, reactjs

I want to experiment with performance of some React components inside my app. I know that ClojureScript's Om framework (https://github.com/swannodette/om) uses some optimization techniques like using immutables with implementing `shouldComponentUpdate()` and rendering on `requestAnimationFrame` change.

Is there plain JavaScript mixin that could introduce rendering based on `requestAnimationFrame`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is possible if you use something like [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) or [webpack](http://webpack.github.io/) to build React from a CommonJS environment, or otherwise produce a custom build of React. That is to say, you *can't* do this if you just use the downloadable, pre-built React.

Check out Pete Hunt's [react-raf-batching project](https://github.com/petehunt/react-raf-batching) for a more comprehensive solution (including rAF polyfills), but here's a minimal example to get this working:

```
var ReactUpdates = require("react/lib/ReactUpdates");

var rafBatchingStrategy = {
  isBatchingUpdates: true,
  batchedUpdates: function(callback, param) {
    callback(param);
  }
};

var tick = function() {
  ReactUpdates.flushBatchedUpdates();
  requestAnimationFrame(tick);
};

requestAnimationFrame(tick);

ReactUpdates.injection.injectBatchingStrategy(rafBatchingStrategy);
```

Comment: Note there are a few (solveable) corner cases you might want to handle: https://github.com/petehunt/react-raf-batching/issues/8

Comment: As of the writing of this comment, `npm install react-raf-batching` requires a peer of react 0.9 and current version is 0.14.5 so it's no longer a quick install. I haven't tried if it just needs minor tweaking or something more involved.